# IOS XPATH through Appium

Tags: ios, automation, appium-ios

Hi I am trying to find xpath of toogle button to on and off for privacy setting in IOS device.

I tried with xpath:- `xpath=${pro_on_off_ios} //XCUIElementTypeSwitch[@name="Link name and photo"]`.

and with this xpath switch is off and on vice versa,but I want to get the value of switch that its on/off and use as per our requirement.

I tried with that for value :  `${Privacy_setting}  AppiumLibrary.Get Text  xpath=${pro_on_off_ios}`.

but its not able to find.

Answer (score 0):

Its solved,

I used get attribute and by value I got the desired result.

`${setting}=  GET ELEMENT ATTRIBUTE     xpath=${//XCUIElementTypeSwitch[@name="Link name and photo"]}    value`